# AAM for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am trying to configure AAM for SharePoint 2010.

The SharePoint site already has a default URL of http://company . I added another URL http://company.xyz.com for the intranet . But when I navigate to http://company.xyz.com I get redirected to the IIS7 default page.

I also changed the IP of http://company.xyz.com and http://company to the same IP.

I also added bindings to the IIS.

Do the two URLS need to point to different IP's .

Comment: Also make sure that the binding for IPv6 address is added to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if you have configured the hosts file in SharePoint.

And then you could disable loop back check in SharePoint.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[CONFIGURE ALTERNATE ACCESS MAPPING IN SHAREPOINT SERVER.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the bindings in IIS is not the recommended or supported method for adding/modifying a url for SharePoint. Instead, extend the web app. Documentation, including explanations of why IIS bindings shouldn't be modified, is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/update-a-web-application-url-and-iis-bindings).

Comment: Thank you Mike for the reply , but extending does not apply for 2010

Comment: Here is a blog post that shows how to extend a web app in 2010, with screen shots: https://blog.backslasher.net/adding-ssl-to-sharepoint-2010-web.html

Comment: Thank you Mike for clarifying that it works on 2010 , but in my case I do not need to extend the web application. All I was trying to do was change the alternate access mapping. Strangely the AAM started working after a day. I remember testing it on the server and it was not working , but then it started  working after a day.